# Can't load content of p:datatable with value of List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to convert a `p:datatable` to pdf using `p:dataExporter`

It works as well using a `List`
However, I encounter an issue when trying to download a datatable with `List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>`

**Backing Bean:**

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Long>> productSet1 = sortedMap1.entrySet();
listMEP1 = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Long>>(productSet1);
```

**XHTML Page:**

```
<p:dataTable id="mydata" emptyMessage="Aucun module touvé." style="font-size: 12px" var="item" value="#{chartChefDepartmentGroupBean.listMEP1}">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.key}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        zaddazd
                        <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/download.png" style="width : 35px; height:35px"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="mydata" fileName="cars"/>
    </h:commandLink>
```

I just got the headers of the table, without any content.

Have you please any idea about solving that?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341683/primefaces-data-exporter-xls-exporting-only-headers-not-rows ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, that is it . It was a problem of @Scope

Comment: Just for clarification Could you please make it as an answer, so I can prove it. Thanks again.

Comment: Well spotted @JasperdeVries

Comment: In case of a duplicate there is no need to create the same answer again.